# 2d boolean array with input values

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, 2d

I have created this code (with the help of Reimeus). How would I achieve to instead of replace every value in the array with true to replace only one pre determined (by z for example) and this always being a value on the top column of the 2d array. Furthermore I would like to how I should start to get instead of the output being true and false it being x for true and y for false but still keeping the array an boolean

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        int y;
        Scanner scanner;
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = scanner.nextInt();
        y = scanner.nextInt();
        boolean[][] cells = new boolean[x][y];

        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            Arrays.fill(cells[i], true);
           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cells[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"it doesnt seem to work"` is not best way to describe problem. What output you get and what you expect?

Comment: Sorry i am new here and still have a lot to learn thanks for the tip though

Comment: No problem. BTW welcome on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays.toString` to display the array content, otherwise the `Object#toString` representation of the `Object` arrays will be displayed

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cells[i]));
```

Comment: Thanks this works now i have a follow up question or two
What would i need to do if i would want to make only 1 piece of the array true and decide where this true should go in the same way as i decide the lenght of the array. Seccondly is there a way in which i could replace the true statement with * and the false statement with -

Comment: @user2777431 This requirements should be part of your original question. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18792459/edit) your question and describe what you need and what do you have problem with.

Comment: I second @Pshemo's comment and please be _very clear_ in what you're asking

Comment: I have just edited my file and i hope i am clear enough in what i am asking

Comment: @user2777431 as a rule on `SO` dont ask _is it possible_ (where answer can be just yes/no) - instead ask "How do I..."

Comment: Okay i have edit my question again as i mentioned to Pshemo i am new here and still learning so I appreciate the help and tips

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Reimeus answer:

> What would I need to do if I would want to make only 1 piece of the array true and decide where this true should go in the same way as I decide the length of the array.

Using fact that `boolean` arrays are by default filled with `false` values you just need to read once index of element that should be set to `true` just like you did with `length`s

```
boolean[][] cells = new boolean[x][y];

int trueX = scanner.nextInt();
int trueY = scanner.nextInt();
cells[trueX][trueY] = true;
```

also don't forget to remove `Arrays.fill(cells[i], true);`

---

> Secondly is there a way in which I could replace the true statement with "*" and the false statement with "-"

You can create second loop that will iterate over elements of row and if it its value is `true` print `*` if not `-` like in this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
        if (cells[i][j])
            System.out.print("* ");
        else
            System.out.print("- ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

or just replace `"true"` string from result of Arrays.toString() with `*` and `"false"` with `"-"`

```
for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cells[i]).replace("true", "*")
            .replace("false", "-"));
}
```

Comment: Yas! The `replace()` is exactly what I was looking for! Tnx mate! Also, you can `for (boolean[] arr : grid) StdOut.println(Arrays.toString(arr).replace()`.